# How to handle Access Denied in .net core with OpenID?

Tags: .net-core, openid-connect

How can i intercept and handle the Acces Denied event in `.net core` with `openid` ? By default it sends a redirect code to `account/accesDenied`, but i'm not using an MVC Client, so that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're making AJAX calls to the .NET backend using something like Angular, and you want status codes 401 and 403 instead of redirects?

This is probably the relevant method from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationEvents`:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Invoked when the client needs to be redirected to the access denied url.
/// </summary>
public Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task> OnRedirectToAccessDenied { get; set; } = context =>
{
    if (IsAjaxRequest(context.Request))
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Location = context.RedirectUri;
        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

Do you see the `IsAjaxRequest()`? By default, .NET doesn't return redirects to AJAX requests, but error status codes.

However, Angular doesn't mark the AJAX requests as such, so .NET doesn't know that it is AJAX.

You can either create an `HttpInterceptor` in Angular that adds the http header "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest", or create your own subclass of `CookieAuthenticationEvents` that never redirects. (Don't forget to register your subclass as dependencies.)